# PHP LDAP, only a few users get returned by ldap_search

Tags: php, ldap, bonjour

I'm working on a PHP project for my job and I ran into an issue. I can't figure out why my query (which just retrive all users) only return 34 results out of 348 entries. It's not depending in which OU they are or anything, it's just like : "You can come, no not you... Yu. No not you, Yu !"

It's always the same 34 persons.

Here's the search filter:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(samaccountname=*))
```

Everything else is fine, it only took me one whole day of work to make the authentification work :3

Ask for more information, I'm new to LDAP, plus PHP and me isn't a love story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to play with the scope (it can be sub, one, or base), if you want all entries from child OUs, you will need to use the "sub" scope. (or SUBTREE)

and you usually can't search subtrees with anonymous binds in many LDAP servers so you have to specify it

Comment: I've found on php.net that "ldap_search" function use by default the sub scope. And it's not an anonymous bind.

Comment: ok, and what if you run an ldapsearch from the command line of your system (assuming it's a unix server), does it return all records ? (using the same filter)

Comment: It's ok, it was a part of a condition in the code I used. it ignores the entry if it haven't any mail adress. (Now I'm wondering why not everyone with a mail adress is listed, but it's a step further ! :D)

Comment: glad you found the issue :)